# GLSL/WebGL for loop error when not using increment operator

Tags: for-loop, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I am trying to do a for loop in a fragment shader and am receiving the following error. I am really confused because this error seems completely irrelevant.

```
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f841f04f600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.
```

The error arrises when I changed

```
for(float j = 0.0 ; j < particlesPerCell; j++){
```

to

```
for(float j = 0.0 ; j < particlesPerCell; j = j + 1.0){
```

Is there any reason for this madness? It works totally fine with j++ and not j = j + 1.0. It isn't a real issue, however it seems really strange and was wondering if anyone can explain this. I tried looking online and didn't find any answers.

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't make a difference, but try casting (remember, C-style casting) your value like `j = j + float(1.0);` or simply `j += float(1.0);` That said, is there any reason you're not using `int` for this? I understand you might be using `j` for calculations within the loop, but it might save you some headaches to just cast it into a temp value for each loop iteration.

Comment: Hmm, so the j += 1.0 works, however j = j + float(1.0) does not.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself now. And I also get an error when using `i = i + 1.0` in a loop, but I get a different error: `'=' : Invalid operator`

I can't find anything in the GLSL documentation about this not being allowed in loop expressions.

So my guess is that this might be platform dependent. It is probably the loop expression that is optimized for performance. But the optimization does not handle any other expression than `i++`, `i += 1` and similar. This is probably because the optimization unrolls the loop into a list of statements, and this is not possible with just any kind of loop expression.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. It's kind of interesting because it really doesn't affect anything since you can just do a += or -=, but still is annothing when you receive misleading debug messages

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are writing output of a shader to a buffer/texture that you are also using as input in the same render.

`j++` and `j = j + 1.0` should have the same result in a for loop, so my guess is that there is something wrong in the rest of your code. And the real question is why that error is not showing all the time.

You need to replicate the error in jsfiddle for us to see

Comment: Hmm I actually just opened up a different shader and put the following in:

 
 for(float test = 0.0; test < 10.0; test = test + 10.0){

 }
  

and it threw the same error. I will make a fiddle later today though and see if it throws errors for others.

Comment: I tried this myself now actually. And I also get an error when using i = i + 1.0 in a loop, but I get a different error: '=' : Invalid operator

Answer (score 0):

Try with an **int** and the total with a **const** if it's possible.

```
const int particlesPerCell = 1000;
for(int j = 0; j < particlesPerCell; j++){
    …
}
```